# FFMPEG Not found

Tags: java, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am writing a java code using [jave api](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php), but the underlying code for api uses ffmpeg, as per requirement I have saved ffmpeg in C:\ffmpeg and added the path of ffmpeg.exe to environment variables on Windows. But I am getting this error

```
it.sauronsoftware.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator copyFile
SEVERE: Could not get native library for ffmpeg-x86.exe
```

I searched on google but unable to find any solution.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but your library wants ffmpeg-x86.exe (not ffmpeg.exe).  Did you try renaming it?

Comment: yes, I tried but no luck.

Comment: Did you try extending FFMpegLocator (as per the jave docs) and override public java.lang.String getFFMPEGExecutablePath() to point at your ffmpeg?

Comment: @spudone thanks, it worked! :) Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were attempting to use the DefaultFFMpegLocator.  Try this instead:

From the Jave docs:

*JAVE gives you an abstract class called it.sauronsoftware.jave.FFMPEGLocator. Extend it. All you have to do is to define the following method:*

*public java.lang.String getFFMPEGExecutablePath()*

*This method should return a file system based path to your custom ffmpeg executable.*

Comment: I have copied ffmpeg-amd64.exe to "C:\windows\system32" path . Then I extend it.sauronsoftware.jave.FFMPEGLocator class. Then I have defined this method . 
public java.lang.String getFFMPEGExecutablePath()
    {
        return "C:\\windows\\system32";
    } But same error is given . Cannot retrieve native file ffmpeg-amd64.exe . Please help me .