# Convert a MP3 file to FLAC using coldfusion

Tags: java, ffmpeg, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want a generic function in ColdFusion through which I can convert audio files to different format.

**What I have tried**

After referring [this java code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/converting-audio-to-different-file-formats) I was trying to implement this in ColdFusion. I have included the .jar file from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjave20jar.htm).

The code I have tried is included below.

```
component { 
    remote void function foo() { 
        WriteOutput("Method foo() called<br>"); 
        // local.path = expandPath("../lib/jave-2.0.jar");
        local.javaObj = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File');
        local.AudioAttributes = createObject("java", "it.sauronsoftware.jave.AudioAttributes");
        local.Encoder = createObject("java", "it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder");
        local.EncodingAttributes = createObject("java", "it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncodingAttributes");

        local.EncodingAttributes.setFormat('flac');
        // local.AudioAttributes.setCodec('libmp3lame');
        //local.EncodingAttributes.setAudioAttributes(audioAttr);
        local.mp3file = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("Manavayanatim.mp3");
        local.flacFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("Manavayanatim.flac");
        try{
            local.Encoder.encode(local.mp3file, local.flacFile, local.EncodingAttributes);
        }catch(Exception e){
            writeDump("Encoding Failed");
        }
    } 
}
```

**Encoder Object**

[image]

**Error I am getting**

[image]

After searching about the error it was seen that `ffmpeg-amd64.exe` file was missing in the location `C:\Windows\System32`. So I downloaded and added that. But still I am not able to solve the error.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068678/ffmpeg-not-found) , that needs to be done, but I am not sure how to do that in CF.

Comment: @RRK - Think that was for version 1. It can't be done in CF. You'd have to do it in java.  Looks live version 2 does away with that by bundling the exe within an extra jar.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this is the same project](https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/wiki/Usage). The usage docs say you also need to download the native jar for your environment. From what I can tell, the library loads and extracts the ffmpeg executable from the native jar (automatically).

> 2. You need the `jave-2.0.jar` file which is your java interface to use
> 3. *In addition you need one of the native libraries, matching your platform*. So for linux 64 bit you download also `jave-2.0-linux64.jar`.
>      This file contents the binary executable for linux 64 bit

That might also explain the error. *If* the library only searches within the native jar, that would explain why copying it to `C:\Windows\...` doesn't help.